# escape characters Mvc 4 asp.net in get function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a GET function in Mvc 4 web api that has to accept a integer and a filename. Filename : \\file server\share\a1.jpg OR http://www.test.net/a2.jpg
I am able to test this function using text boxes & submit button. When I type in as URL, I get http 400 error
Localhost://API/myapi/get/1/\\file server\share\a1.jpg
I cannot ask the user to URL encode before entering the Url.
Any suggestions as to how to handle this? 
Thx
R

Answer (score 0):

Changing `GET` to `POST` will solve the problem.

If you really need to use the `GET` method, you can encode the input data with [encodeURI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/xh9be5xc%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) method when user submitting the form using JQuery [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function.

e.g.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $("#filename").val(encodeURI($("#filename").val()));
});
```

Comment: I want the users to be able to call this function as URL. How can I call a POST as URL??

Comment: We cannot call a POST as URL. Is there any special reason to call this as URL ?

Comment: I want the user to be able to call an url and save ID and filename/ url to database. Since I cannot call POST in a url, I use GET function to call POST [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        public void GetInfo(int ID, string URL_FilePath)
        { Post(ID,URL_FilePath); }
           [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public void Post([FromBody]SomeObj value)
        {